# How to record (x,y) of a gesture at a fixed frequency?

Tags: android, gesture

I am now trying to record some (x,y) of a gesture. Now I have referred to some material and found that OnTouch function can help us get the (x,y) of the point that we touch down. However, I now need to move my finger and record the (x,y) of the points in the path at a fixed rate. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code it will help you.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //invoke when you will touch down finger on screen
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //invoke when you will move finger on screen
            fingerMove(event.getX(), event.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //invoke when you will up finger from screen
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I use java to develop the program. Do you have java version of this code?@Dharmender Manral

Comment: This function seems to only record the starting point and the end point, but I also need to record the points beween them at a fixed rate. How can I do that?@Dharmender Manral

Comment: It will continue listen coordinate with fixed rate.